# Color only a specific boxplot among many using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to specify the color of one boxplot among many using ggplot.

For example, say I were using the Orthodont dataset that comes with the nlme package.

How would I specify that I would like the boxplot for males to be green?

```
> head(Orthodont)
Grouped Data: distance ~ age | Subject
  distance age Subject  Sex
1     26.0   8     M01 Male
2     25.0  10     M01 Male
3     29.0  12     M01 Male
4     31.0  14     M01 Male
5     21.5   8     M02 Male
6     22.5  10     M02 Male
> ggplot(data = Orthodont) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(Sex), y = distance))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have many levels of x variable (for example `Subject`) and you don't need to show colors in legend then you could plot over another boxplot layer only for one level with color you need.

```
ggplot(data = Orthodont) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = Subject, y = distance))+
      geom_boxplot(data=Orthodont[Orthodont$Subject=="M01",],
                        aes(x = Subject, y = distance),fill="green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There might be a way to just color one, but you can just manually change the fill to a different color. The default fill seems to be white. You can also do `values = c(NA, "red")`.

```
ggplot(Orthodont) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(Sex), y = distance, fill = Sex)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "white"))
```

[image]